# boton que haga un fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

tengo este codigo y quiero que un botón accione este código y que se haga el fetch, probé de varias maneras nose como meter el botón acá

Comment: No elimines el código de la pregunta, pues no solo la hace lucir fuera de las reglas de [ask], sino que además deja *mal ubicada* a la respuesta

Comment: Quiero eliminé la pregunta por eso clickee y no la elimina

Comment: Bajo tu pregunta existe el enlace de eliminar y es ese el que debes usar

Comment: Si eso hice pero nada

Comment: Nada?, no hace nada o te da algún aviso?

Comment: Me dice votar para eliminar la pregunta pongo que si y nada

Comment: Cuál enlace????

Comment: Si dice eliminar y apretó y me dice lo que te digo de los votos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar un *listener* al botón poniendo dentro todo el código que lanza el `fetch`, algo así:

```js
/* Creamos una referencia al elemento */
var btnFetch = document.getElementById("btnFetch");
/* Le asignamos un listener a los clicks del mismo*/
btnFetch.onclick = function(event) {

  /* Aquí tu código del fetch*/
  console.log("Prueba de que funciona, si el fetch no tiene errores");

};
```

```html
<button id="btnFetch">Lanzar</button>
```